# MySQL Query wouldn't execute

Tags: mysql, performance

This MySQL Query doesn't give any output instead turns into the screen as attached below:

```
SELECT sfog.entity_id, 
  sfog.status AS Status,
  CONCAT(
    (SELECT customer_entity_varchar.value 
       from customer_entity_varchar  
       where attribute_id = '5' 
       AND customer_entity_varchar.entity_id = ms.mageproownerid  
    ),' ', 
    (SELECT customer_entity_varchar.value 
     from customer_entity_varchar 
     where attribute_id = '7' 
       AND customer_entity_varchar.entity_id = ms.mageproownerid 
    )
 ) AS Seller , 
 sfog.increment_id AS OrderNo , 
 sfosh.created_at AS 'Invoice Date', 
 mo.tracking_number AS 'Tracking Number', 
 CONCAT(sfoa.firstname, ' ', sfoa.lastname) AS 'Customer Name' 
from sales_flat_order_grid sfog, 
  sales_flat_order_address sfoa, 
  marketplace_saleslist ms, 
  customer_entity_varchar cev, 
  sales_flat_order_status_history sfosh, 
  marketplace_orders mo 
where sfog.status = 'delivered' 
  AND sfoa.parent_id = sfog.entity_id 
  AND ms.mageorderid = sfog.entity_id 
  AND cev.entity_id = ms.mageproownerid 
  AND sfosh.parent_id = sfog.entity_id 
  AND sfosh.entity_name = 'invoice' 
  AND mo.order_id = sfog.entity_id 
GROUP BY sfog.entity_id
```

[ScreenShot of How Query Ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bzSf.png)

Comment: What's the purpose of the screenshot?

Comment: If the question is about the query then split it on multiple lines and format it nicely to be readable.

Comment: What happens if you run a different query?

Comment: What it *looks* like depends on the client you are using (which you provided no details of). What does it say in your logs? What happens when you use a different client? Does the client you are using support the use of the placeholders in your query?

Comment: You are selecting non aggregate columns with `GROUP BY`.  This is logically wrong.

Comment: Also, if those subqueries could return more than one value, this would also cause your query to fail.

Comment: @axiac The purpose of the screenshot is to show that it abruptly stops executing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The subqueries are not returning more than single row.

Comment: @symcbean I am using adminer.php and I have no idea if it shows logs.

Comment: I think I need to optimize this query if any one can help.

Comment: Is your issue that the query doesn't run at all, or that it doesn't perform the way you want?

Comment: @Urja the screenshot doesn't reveal anything. You are using a web application to run the query and this adds several more reasons to fail. It might be a timeout on the server-side code of the application, it might be a connectivity issue, it might be anything. Run the query using the command line `mysql` client (or write code that runs the query and inspects the error message returned by the MySQL server, if any) to find out what really happened.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The issue is that the query isn't executing at all. But I think it may be cause it runs into infinite loop or something.

Comment: There are so many problems I can only suggest that you take apart the query until it starts working.

Comment: @axiac I tried running it through code as you suggested and it ends in 504 Gateway Time Out